# Transform String value to bytearray java

Tags: java, string, object, casting, arrays

I have a string which contains the byte array's String value for example like this [B@42031498
I want to retrieve the `String` content as `byte[]` ? How can I  do that ?

**PS :** converting the string with `String.getBytes()` method doesn't work . It converts the string but doesn't give me the value as byte array. It works [like this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-string-to-byte-in-java/).

If It's is not possible is there a way to get byte[] from Object in java (and always without converting)

Comment: Pass your `byte[]` to `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: `[B@42031498` is result of calling `toString` on array object. If you want to print content of array then iterate over it and print each element, or just use `Arrays.toString(yourArray)`.

Comment: If it does not give you the output as a byte array what does it give you the output as?

Comment: You don't specify the encoding you want those bytes into... The JVM's default encoding will be used and it may not be the same from one JVM to another

Comment: The problem is that I'm receiving my Byte[] in "Object" format through java SocketIo lib. but I need to get the Byte[] content of Object. I tried to convert it to string as intermediary format but it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `[B@42031498` has already been saved into a String, there is no way you can get this back to the originating byte array. Look at the following example:

```
String str = "[B@42031498";
byte[] ba = str.getBytes();

String s = new String(ba);
System.out.println(s);
```

This will output `[B@42031498`

Answer (score 1):

> converting the string with String.getBytes() method doesn't work . It converts the string but doesn't give me the value as byte array.

[Yes it does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29).

You have two problems:

- you try and print the array directly; you should use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29), otherwise the `.toString()` method of the array itself is called;
- you don't specify the encoding; you should really use `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to have the same result on all environments.

In the same manner, building a string from a byte array should be done using the correct encoding: `new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the byte array as below and you will get the byte value :

```
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
```

The output `B@42031498` you get because of Object class toString() method .

```
public String toString()
  {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done:

```
 byte[] array = ....
 String result = array.toString();
```

What you (probably) want:

```
 String result = new String(array, "UTF-8");
```